# Having Buttons Give Roles to a User on Interaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Roles are not being given to the user upon interaction The interaction reads "Interaction failed" after 3 seconds This command is to create a permanent reaction role embed with buttons

```
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (interaction.isChatInputCommand())
    {
        const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
  
        if (!command) {
            console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
            return;
        }
  
        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error executing ${interaction.commandName}`);
            console.error(error);
        }
    }else if (interaction.isButton())
    {
      const member = interaction.options.getMember('target');

      const role_heHim = interaction.options.getRole('814293352157282325');
      
      if(!member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'He/Him'))
      {
        member.roles.add(role_heHim);
      }else if(member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'He/Him'))
      {
        member.roles.remove(role_heHim);
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Give the role to the user